# Can't reformat laptop after sudo rm -rf /

Tags: macos

I had a friend who was trying to be funny and mess with my laptop and he typed in the command: `sudo rm -rf /`

This completely messed up my laptop. So I decided to reformat my Mac. When I try to reinstall it it says "volume contains a macOS or OS X installation which may be damaged.

Any suggestions of what I could do?

Comment: That's no friend, for sure.  But when you say you "try to reinstall it" do you mean you are booting from recovery, or an install disk/USB?  We need more details to better assist you.  You Mac model and the version of macOS you are installing is also important.  Lastly, have you tried using Disk Utility to wipe the drive completely so you can start fresh?

Comment: @Allan I am trying to boot from recovery. I am running on a late 2015 macbook pro. I'm not sure which OS I am installing. I just tried using disk utility to erase my main drive. Now I'm stuck at internet recovery mode for some reason it won't let me go back to the utility screen using command + R. Internet recovery mode gets about halfway and gives me -2003F error.

Comment: Try Internet Recovery - `Cmd-Opt-R` and reinstall that way.

Comment: If command+option+R (as suggested by @Allan) doesn't work, have you got access to another Mac? Maybe your _friend_ has one?  Either way, if you can access another Mac let me know what it is.